# SSIS Data flow does not write the first few batches

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, bulk

I have a data flow in SSIS that will randomly not import records.  I have been working on this for weeks so at this point I have `rowcount`s in the SSIS package, `count(*)` in SQL to verify the rows inserted, triggers to the table to record what was inserted when and SSIS package logging on inserts.

This problem happens EXTREMELY randomly. It can not happen for days at a time and then suddenly happen in the morning, in the afternoon, whenever.

**So here is my flow:**

1. Data comes out of multiple flat files through a single flat file connection and source.
2. I use a `rowcount` to count the rows.  For example lets say it's 1000 rows.
3. I add a derived column to the flow
4. I again use `rowcount` to count the rows. This has always matched #2
5. I then parse the line using a c# script
   (don't ask why I don't just delimit, not relevant, not the cause and
   the file is wonky).

   **EDIT:** Since it was asked - the c# script has multiple try catch for parsing and error rows are caught and added the an error output instead of the normal output. I have tested this and it is working as expected.  I also have a `rowcount` off the error output. This has been 0 in all cases where the issue I'm talking about has occurred.  It does have values in other cases (bad parse of XML) but that is not relevant to this issue nor fixable as the file itself is bad. After the error `rowcount` I bulk insert these rows to a different table - this insert has been getting the correct counts in all instances.
6. I use `rowcount` to count the rows.  This number has so far always matched #2 as well
7. The record is inserted into the table using a OLE DB destination.  Table lock is off, Check contraints is on, Keep nulls is off, Keep identity is null, max commit size is 3500 and rows per batch is blank. Error output is set to redirect.
   a.I use SSIS package Log to verify and the log will state that it is STILL 1000 rows
8. I use error output to a `rowcount`, this number is 0
9. I have addition retry inserts with lower commits etc. No other work on the table is done and since error output on #8 is 0 every time so far, these parts aren't even hit, so again - not relevant.
10. Next in the task flow is running a count(*) on the table and other logging (see below), it will have a lower number i.e. 700.

**Now some interesting information from logs I've collected**

- Using some hefty logging, I use a join on the inserts to get the specific rows in the SQL table that relate to each file that was inserted. The files that were inserted first will only have one (1) record.  **Why one - I am not sure.**  This will happen for typically two to three of the files.  After that, the next file may have some or all of the file - i.e. 120 rows of a 200 row file
- If I look at the trigger data results, the trigger log shows the same thing: the first few inserts only have 1 row followed by about half of the normal insert in the next insert (typically my data flow has 450 records in a batch so this might be around 200 records for example).  After that the remaining batches have the entire 450 rows until the last batch (for the obvious reason of it running out of lines to insert).

**Conclusion:**

For whatever reason there is some reason that the inserts will only insert one row in the first few batches, and then continue to write all the records in the remaining batches. The problem is that SSIS apparently THINKS it is inserting all the rows (as the Package Log states all rows were inserted and there are 0 error rows, but a `count(*)` for the table reveals differently).

**Reasons I've come up with:**

- Is it something like a Use database statement or some other statement that has to run before the inserts take place and for some reason SSIS isn't waiting on this? I ran a SQL trace and the only statements I can find on the same spid before the inserts begin are

  ```
   exec [sys].sp_bcp_dbcmptlevel [DBNAME]
   set fmtonly on
   select * from [dbo].[TableName]
   set fmtonly off
  ```

I have `Validate external metadata` off on the insert so I'm unsure why it's even doing this step or how to stop it or if that's even necessary.

- Is there some sort of blocking? Perhaps - but why does it consistently seem to block only the first few inserts and why is one record still inserted of the batch?  If it was blocking I was suspect no records would be inserted. Besides, the way the table is set up there should be no blocking on these records (a parent table is checked for what can be inserted).
- Foreign Keys? Some other constraint?  No - there are no FK's and the only constraint is a default `getdate()` for a column.
- Bug in SQL and/or SSIS?  My patch level for SQL is SQL Server 2008 R2 (Sp3) - 10.50.6220.0  The version for SSIS is 2008.
- Some sort of memory contention?  The memory on the machine is typically only 50% used.  I have not seen huge spikes on it.

**Other information:**

- The server runs the SSIS package and the SQL Server on the same server,  The SQL Server does have the memory limit set so as not to conflict with the memory usage of the SSIS package.

I've seen various other questions asked in multiple places - the closest that sounds exactly like my issues seems to be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089008/data-flow-task-executing-successfully-but-not-writing-any-rows-to-excel-file) where they just suggest rebuilding the data flow task. Perhaps I'm just anal but I want to know why this happens before I go doing that as I don't want to have to always have to write in checks to every single SSIS package I make to ensure that "hey! It really does write all the rows it says it writes".

**EDIT**: Package Log of the data flow from a run where the error occurred. I have OnError, OnInformation, OnPreExecute, OnPostExecute, OnProgress, OnTaskFailed, BufferSizeTuning.

I did not have OnWarning before, I have just added that and will update this if/when the problem happens again if any warning info is given.

```
<Messages>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:14">The processing of file "D:\636885940052243508" has started.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:14">Execute phase is beginning.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The total number of data rows processed for file "D:\636885940052243508" is 1020.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The processing of file "D:\636885940052243508" has ended.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The processing of file "D:\636885940088814813" has started.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The total number of data rows processed for file "D:\636885940088814813" is 3.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The processing of file "D:\636885940088814813" has ended.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The processing of file "D:\636885940056841575" has started.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The total number of data rows processed for file "D:\636885940056841575" is 1077.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The processing of file "D:\636885940056841575" has ended.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The processing of file "D:\636885940090153045" has started.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The total number of data rows processed for file "D:\636885940090153045" is 5.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The processing of file "D:\636885940090153045" has ended.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:15">The processing of file "D:\636885940052788627" has started.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:16">The total number of data rows processed for file "D:\636885940052788627" is 1005.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:16">The processing of file "D:\636885940052788627" has ended.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:16">The processing of file "D:\636885940089158218" has started.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:16">The total number of data rows processed for file "D:\636885940089158218" is 2.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:16">The processing of file "D:\636885940089158218" has ended.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:16">The processing of file "D:\636885940046337791" has started.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:16">The total number of data rows processed for file "D:\636885940046337791" is 962.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:16">The processing of file "D:\636885940046337791" has ended.
</Message>
```

...skipping cause it's hundreds of lines (yes the counts do match if I was to add them up)

```
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">The final commit for the data insertion in "component "Insert" (1886)" has started.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">The final commit for the data insertion  in "component "Insert" (1886)" has ended.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">The final commit for the data insertion in "component "Retry Insert" (2051)" has started.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">The final commit for the data insertion  in "component "Retry Insert" (2051)" has ended.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">Post Execute phase is beginning.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">"component "Malformed - Bad Parse" (10)" wrote 0 rows.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">"component "Insert" (1886)" wrote 36581 rows.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">"component "Retry Insert RBAR" (1933)" wrote 0 rows.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">"component "Malformed - Failed Insert" (1994)" wrote 0 rows.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">"component "Retry Insert" (2051)" wrote 0 rows.
</Message>
  <Message StartTime="2019-03-19T12:09:38">Cleanup phase is beginning.
</Message>
</Messages>
```

Comment: Some basics you probably covered but to just check.  Does your step have fail on failure or continue?  The records not inserting may be failing for some reason so it does not insert those, but continues processing?  In your c# code are you trapping the errors correctly to display them?  Maybe they are being ignored/not captured properly.

Comment: My c# has multiple try catch for the parse yes.  I don't believe that's it because the rowcount coming out of the c# is the same as going into the parse script AND I don't get anything reporting errors from the script.   The step itself has fail on failure but it is not failing.  It apparently thinks the insert completed 100% successfully.

Comment: If you have OnError, OnWarning, OnProgress logged can you give us a snippet of the log surround that workflow.

Comment: Your catching the errors in your C# code but what are you doing with the errors when they happen?  Are they being sent up to SSIS, because you can capture and handle them and SSIS will never see them.  Depending on where your counts are coming from you may be getting the counts prior to errors and errors are not seen if there not pushed up to SSIS from the C# code.